# KnockoutJS dynamically set input's value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scope, subscribe, parents

I'm trying to dynamically set select input's value using knockoutjs data-bind. If I just put `value: $parents[0].selectedSubcategory` in the `<select>` element's attributes, it works fine.  But when I try to pass the value in, it doesn't work.

My view looks like this -

```
<div data-bind="with: QuestionFilter">
  <form>
    <div data-bind="foreach: details">
      <select data-bind="options: subcategories, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'categoryID', value: subcategoriesValue">
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  ko.applyBindings({
    categories = <?php echo $categories; ?>,
    details = ko.observableArray([])       
  });
</script>
```

And my JS looks like this -

```
function QuestionFilter(categories, details) {
  var self = this;
  self.subcategories = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedSubcategory = ko.observable();

    function search(nameKey, myArray){
      for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].parentCategory_id === nameKey) {
          self.subcategories.push(myArray[i]);
        }
      }
    }   
    search(2, categories);
    details.push({ firstName: self.subcategories(), lastName: self.selectedSubcategory()});
  });

  self.selectedSubcategory.subscribe(function(subcategory) {
    function subsearch(nameKey, myArray){
      for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].parentCategory_id === nameKey) {
          self.superSubcategories.push(myArray[i]);
    }
      }
    }
   subsearch(subcategory, categories);
   details.push({ firstName: self.superSubcategories()});
  });
```

In addition to the above, I have tried using `lastName: $parents[0].self.selectedSubcategory()`, with and without quotes.  I have also tried setting the `<select>` element's value like this: `value: $parents[0].lastName` also with and without quotes and `+`, but no joy.

Any thoughts or clarification needed?

Comment: It is not clear what value you are wanting, since the `<select>` is inside of a `foreach` binding you are scoped to the context of a `detail`. If the property you want is inside of a `detail` object, simply put that property as the `value` binding. If you want to step out a level, then you use `$parent` and obviously `$root` will give you the base bound model. As a side note, `firstName: self.subcategories()` seems strange. Describing a generalization of the end result of what you are trying to achieve would also help in answering your question.

Comment: Thanks for having a look.  I want to be able to pass `$parent.self.selectedSubcategory()` via `details.push()` into `<select>` value attribute.

Comment: What is `details` supposed to represent because you are performing a `.push` of differently structured objects. Since you are pushing `self.selectedSubcategory()` as `lastName` you could use that property, but the fact that the other `.push` has only a `firstName` will cause issues. You would also probably want to make `lastName` an observable.

Comment: `details` is an observable array.  I understand that I would need to use firstName and lastName every time, but I can't add lastName in the second instance until it works in the first.  I'm not sure how much good making lastName an observable would be as I just want to push a value into it.